# how to get string from a line of strings?

Tags: c++

I have following string:

```
"hw_core_detectionhook::Iocard const*"
```

I have to get only first part, i.e all text present before space, i.e I need the  `"hw_core_detectionhook::Iocard"` part only.

Comment: Is it a `std::string` or a `char*`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s.substr(0,s.find_first_of(" "));
```

Comment: thanks but above expression wil provide me second part i.e const*

Comment: I've tried and it seems to provide the first part: http://www.ideone.com/Q84m9. If s.find_first_of would be the first argument - then it would provide " const*".

Answer (score 3):

```
std::stringstream ss;

ss << "hw_core_detectionhook::Iocard const*";

std::string s;

ss >> s;

std::cout << s;
```

Output:

```
hw_core_detectionhook::Iocard
```

See the complete demo online : http://www.ideone.com/w9l1C

Comment: I didn't know stringstream would do that. Thanks. +1